# Spring MVC not showing the desired result

Tags: spring-mvc

I am new to spring MVC and maven also. I created a maven web project in eclipse. Add dependencies for spring and run the project, but i am not getting the desired result. Here is my project structure

[image: Project Structure in eclipse]

When i run the project then i get the result `Hello World` which is my index.jsp

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <title>Hello</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Hello World</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

But when i change to url `http://localhost:8080/Spring_Maven/jsp/hello` i get `HTTP Status 500 error`. And when i change to url `http://localhost:8080/Spring_Maven/jsp/hello.jsp` then i get the output `${message}`

Here is my hello.jsp page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <title>Hello</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>${message}</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is my web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

    <display-name>Spring_Maven</display-name>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>springMaven-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>springMaven-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/springMaven-dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

</web-app>
```

here is my springMaven-dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
                   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd 
                   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context  
                   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="pk.training.basitMahmood.springMaven.controller" />

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/jsp/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Here are the list of dependencies that i added through maven

[image: spring dependencies]

What i am doing wrong?

Comment: one thing that i found during searching is that the maven dependencies should be copy to `WEB-INF/lib` folder. But it is not copying. Although when i go to `project properties --> Deployment Assembly` i have `Meven depencies map to WEB-INF/lib`. But there is no lib folder in my WEB-INF. I don't know yet whether i have to manually create this folder or not. I have also tried by creating folder manually, but jars are not copying to lib folder don't know yet why ... but this is my findings till yet :)

Answer (score 1):

Finally i made it work :). But i want to share so people with new to maven and eclipse could save their time.

First i installed the `m2e eclipse WTP plugin` and then create the maven project as i described in my question. The thing that you need to do is to add the compiler plugin and JDK version in your pom.xml else each time you do `right click on project --> Maven --> Update project` you get an error in the marker tab about `JRE and java EE configuration problem`. You also ned to change in project facets by doing `right click on project --> properties --> Project facets --> Change java version`. Here is the snippet of the `pom.xml`.

```
<build>
    <finalName>SpringMavenHelloWorld</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Then in the web.xml i updated the servelt schema, and i found that i need to define my servet-dispatcer.xml file in both dispatcher-servlet and in the servlet context. Here is my web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
                        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    version="3.0">
    <display-name>Spring_Maven</display-name>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>springMaven-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/springMaven-dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>springMaven-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/springMaven-dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <welcome-file-list>
            <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

</web-app>
```

Here is the structure of my project. I changed it a bit. Made a spring folder in WEB-INF and move the dispatcher servlet in it.

[image: Final structure of my project]

Although there is no lib folder in `WEB-INF` but everything is working fine. The thing that took my time so much is to define both `servletcontext param` and `servelet init-param`. If i only define servlet init param like

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>springMaven-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/springMaven-dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>springMaven-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<!--  
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/springMaven-dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
-->
```

then i got the error that

```
SEVERE: Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: 
IOException parsing XML document from ServletContext resource 
[/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]; nested exception is 
java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext 
resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]
```

and if i define only the context param like

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>springMaven-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <!--  
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/springMaven-dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    -->
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>springMaven-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/springMaven-dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

then i got the error that

```
SEVERE: Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: 
IOException parsing XML document from ServletContext resource 
[/WEB-INF/springMaven-dispatcher-servlet.xml]; nested exception is 
java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource
 [/WEB-INF/springMaven-dispatcher-servlet.xml]
```

But defining both solve the issue. Now when i do `right click on my project --> run on server` then i get the page `Hello World` with url `http://localhost:8080/SpringMavenHelloWorld/` and when i change it to `http://localhost:8080/SpringMavenHelloWorld/hello` then i get my desired output that is

[image]

Hope this will help others too. Thank you :)